# Cannot connect to Amazon Redshift via Sql Workbench(JDBC) timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I added inbound rules for my security group for my ip and it was working until yesterday. I cannot connect anymore(timeout error). Even if i I add a all traffic and anywhere rule nothing changes.
Any help will be gladly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: you aren't able to initiate a connection, or your queries are timing out? also, are you behind a firewall? can you try using a different internet connection?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes it was a timeout. I was connecting with no problem until i started to access redshift cluster with lambda func. Then i was able to access cluster with lambda,  was not able to access with Sql Workbench. After 2 days of work terminated and created new cluster and db but this time i chose an elastic ip for public ip of my cluster and i am able to connect from Sql Workbench. It didnt work at my first try but it did work after a while and i dont have any idea why. It was probably an issue about public ip(maybe clusters automatic eip assignment has a bug).